# Socket.io don't emit after disconnect event

Tags: socket.io

I want to send data from the server to the client after a disconnect socket.io event occurs.

Server :

```
const clients = {};
io.on('connection', socket => {
    clients[socket.id] = socket;
    console.log('connect : ' + socket.id);
    socket.emit('socket-connect', 'connected');

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        socket.emit('socket-disconnect', 'disconnected');
        delete clients[socket.id];
        console.log('disconnect : ' + socket.id);
    });
});
```

Client :

```
const  socket = openSocket('localhost');

socket.on('socket-connect', data => {
    console.log(data);
});

socket.on('socket-disconnect', data => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

If socket connected, the server send a connect message to client and it works, but it does not send interrupted messages to the client if the disconnection occurs.

`console.log('disconnect : ' + socket.id);` on server showing disconnect with the socket.id.

I'm using socket.io v2.0.4 both on server and client.

How can I send data from the server if a socket disconnect event occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event: `disconnect` is fired upon disconnection. This simply means, for some reason, there is no connection between the client and the server.
So in this situation, you cannot send data to the client as the client is not connected. Disconnection may happen if the client's network is not available(read Internet failure) or the client environment(ex: browser) crashed or the user closed the tab.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, so is impossible to send data from the server to the client after a disconnect socket.io event occurs or there are other ways to do that?

Comment: Yes, it's not possible. Think as if you are out of cell network coverage you cannot receive SMS.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation

Comment: This event is there for doing some stuff on server side when client disconnects. For ex: you can make the client leave from a room. P.S. You can wait for some time for clients to reconnect before doing the task for "disconnet".